# sysctl: cannot stat /proc.sys/net/ipv4/tcp_frto_response

Tags: networking, tcp-ip

I'm trying to tune some tcp parameters to enhance the performance of the wireless network I have. One of those system parameters are `tcp_frto` and `tcp_frto_response`. The first value I was able to read and change but when I try to read the second one, I get this message:

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc.sys/net/ipv4/tcp_frto_response
```

Then I went to that specific directory and listed the sysctl parameters, and `tcp_frto_response` doesn't exist, and I cant read its value. I also added that in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and rebooted the machine but not yet able to find it. How to resolve this issue.

Note: in the TCP man page of ubuntu, this value was set since Linux 2.6.22

Answer (score 1):

It seems the parameter has been removed because of the F-RTO refactor. According to the link, newer implementation implements RFC5682.

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?id=9b44190dc114c1720b34975b5bfc65aece112ced

Also, the tcp_frto parameter has been changed to accept boolean value (0 or non-0), instead of 0, 1 and 2.